# Where to find the package com.google.android.gms?

Tags: android, firebase

I try to include in my java file the instruction

```
import com.google.android.gms.appinvite;
```

however when i try to compile i receive the error:

> error: package com.google.android.gms does not exist
>
> com.google.android.gms.appinvite is part of firebase: https://firebase-dot-google-developers.appspot.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/appinvite/package-summary?authuser=2&hl=ID

Where to find the package com.google.android.gms?

Answer (score 0):

You can download `com.google.android.gms` using the sdk manager in Android studio

follow this guide in the docs: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: i did, under android-sdk-windows i have the folder: extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/ but now how to use it in my comand line: javac -Xlint:deprecation -cp android.jar -d output\classes src\com\MySource.java ??

Comment: check the version you have and make sure it matches the version you need

Comment: yes, i did, but how now to compile under javac.exe ?

Comment: ok, forget about javac... just what i need, is where to find the .jar file containing the package com.google.android.gms ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using different version of Google Play service like
 `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'`

Comment: thanks adam, but how to do this ? my comand line is: javac -Xlint:deprecation -cp android.jar -d output\classes src\com\MySource.java

Comment: you can follow this instruction [click me :)](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Comment: you can run this in the command line `libraryDependencies += "com.google.android.gms"  % "play-services" % "7.8.0"`

Comment: or follow this link and it will show you similar example [click](http://www.thedevline.com/2014/03/install-google-play-services-sdk-in.html)

Comment: i can't find the jar file :( under extra\google\google_play_services\ their is no .Jar file that i can use :(

Comment: So you have to install the google play service manually by command line or from android sdk. why do you need the jar file anyway?  by changing the app to project in the folder explorer and go to build.gradle file and paste the compile code 'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0' in the dependencies with others then build your project.